# Not able to edit/configure Standard Objects detail/definition page

Tags: standard-objects, activities

Not able to edit/configure Standard Objects detail/definition page as the buttons edit/delete are not available whereas they are available for custom objects. I want to enable activities for Contact Object but can't edit anything. Do not understand why the buttons are not visible, please help #Standard Object #Quick Action #Activity Management

Edition - Enterprise Edition

Profile - System Admin

Org - Sales Cloud

[image]

Comment: This is standard behaviour. No one sees an Edit or Delete button on Standard Objects. They can't be deleted. Have you tried to add the Activities related list in the page layout?